# Tag (select) files in multiple directories

Tags: mc

In Midnight Commander I can only tag files in one directory at a time. If I tag some files in a directory and then change to another directory to tag some more, the original files are automatically un-tagged.

What I want to do is have files in different directories tagged at the same time so that I can copy/move them all in one go, rather than waste time with a new copy/move operation for each source directory.

Is this possible in mc? Or if not are there any Linux file managers that allow this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**peterph**'s answer led me to discover mc's 'External panelize' feature.

Using `find -type d` as the external command causes every directory to be displayed, enabling directories from multiple locations to be selected simultaneously, for copying/moving etc. This is what I wanted to accomplish originally.

Similarly, searching `*` using the standard 'Find File' facility results in every file and directory being displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is *directly* possible in MC nor in any other file manager.

What you could do though (in MC):

1. serach for files (<kbd>M - ?</kbd>), choose whatever fits, then "panelize" the results, and you'll end up with the list of files from various directories.
2. writing a simple script, that would take list of filenames, prepend them with a directory name and save those to a file. You could then give the script the tagged files with <kbd>Ctrl + x</kbd>, <kbd>t</kbd> or create a menu entry that would do the same. Feed the contents of the file to whatever machinery you need once it contains all files you want.

It would make an interesting feature though.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer led me to discover the 'External panelize' feature, which more-or-less does what I want.

Comment: Heh, I totally missed that functionality - thanks for pointing me at it. :)